# How to Execute Stored Procs sequentially?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, execution, database-performance

I have a stored procedure which needs to sequentially execute one after another (after completion of one and it should go for next stored procedure execution).

For example:

```
Exec [dbo].[usp_UpdateUTCDateForCustom] CacheExpirationPolicy , ModifiedOn
GO
Exec [dbo].[usp_UpdateUTCDateForCustom] Consumable , CreatedOn
GO
Exec [dbo].[usp_UpdateUTCDateForCustom] Consumable , ModifiedOn
```

How can I run the above stored procedures to run sequentially?

Comment: What's wrong with the example above?

Comment: You **ARE** executing them sequentially...... so what is your question, really??

Comment: Will the 3 SPS Executes at a time or will go sequantially..One after the other..
I need to execute the SPS one by one..i.e., after the completion of SP1, SP2 shud execute and go on..

Comment: That's exactly what will happen here: the first procedure executes, and if no errors are encountered, the second will run after the first is done, and so on. No parallelism - one after the other